# Querying JObject Inner element

Tags: c#, json.net

I would like to query all the heading property that contains value "test" using Csharp from the below the JObject and it should return JObject object type.

I tried the following option but no luck. https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenWithLinq.htm

Jobject:

```
{
  "numFound": "10",
  "documents": [
    {
      "document": {
        "Someid": "125526",
        "id": "3922127",
        "elements": {
          "heading": {
            "elementType": "text",
            "value": "test"
          },
          "city": {
            "elementType": "text",
            "value": "test-2"
          }
        },
        "document": {
          "Someid": "225526",
          "id": "4922127",
          "elements": {
            "heading": {
              "elementType": "text",
              "value": "test"
            },
            "city": {
              "elementType": "text",
              "value": "test-3"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Explain what you want the result to look like. Query is a bit vague especially when you say you want a JObject as the result type.

Comment: Please, share what you've already tried